# What is the bright star or planet in eastern sky on dec 18 2018?

Tags: galaxy

What is the bright star or planet in eastern sky on Dec 18 2018 in Laurens SC. It is very bright and beautiful on a clear night. I have been seeing it for about a month or more. It seems to follow the same path as the moon. This object is sighted at sundown to sunset. Is it a star or a planet? It is very bright and does not twinkle.

Comment: where is Laurens SC?

Comment: @DrChuck I'm guessing [Laurens, South Carolina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laurens,_South_Carolina)

Comment: There are many different bright stars in the eastern sky at your location (presumably) early in the evening. Please give us more information about what you are seeing. Can you give us an exact true heading for the star and its altitude? Can you give us an exact time for that coordinate? Can you tell us what color it is? Do you see any star patterns or clear constellations around it?Separately, have you tried using Stellarium on your computer to identify what it is?